# Proper DB access authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, authentication

We're in the process of developing a simple webapp that will be made available on our intranet.  Access to the app will be controlled with a "user" table: If your network login is present in the table, you can use the app.

The app, itself, will make use of a SQL database.  In our current dev setup, we're all admins of the dev database, so we have complete access.  When this gets deployed to Production, however, we've got a couple of options for authenticating to the database.

Does it make sense to grant each appropriate user his or her own credentials on the data, or should the users all share a single application-level user account on the database?

Comment: Can't you add users to different **roles** and granting the access permission on role basis??

Comment: Do you need to track the actions performed by each user on the database or you don't care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating separate user accounts for each app user complicates things in my experience.  If there isn't a security specification you have to design to, I would create a single logon for the app, create a database role, grant permissions to the role, and add the logon to the role.

You can still audit user actions if you use this method by passing user names as input parameters on your stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Per-user access credentials will result in a logistical nightmare in all but the smallest user bases.  It also complicates matters ever so slightly in a web environment.

The most common approach I've seen (and used) is to use a dedicated user per application.  All access goes through that username/password.

Your application will be performing authorization in any event so you can audit the user name performing the various actions if you need to.